# How can I use a plugin mapping in my own mapping?

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-vim-commentary

I often repeat the following commands when I edit code:

- `yy` - yank the line
- `gcc` - comment out the line (so that I can visually see all the changes later)
- `p` - paste back the copied version what I will edit
- `i` - jump into insert mode

I tried to do the mapping as

```
nnoremap yc yygccpi
```

The problem seems to be with the commentary plugin's key-combination. Even if I remap `gcc` to `yc`, nothing happens. Other bindings, like `yyp` and `3l`, are working.
The `nnoremap` is at the end of my vimrc, well after the `packloadall` command.

How could I accomplish this keymapping, and what was the problem?

Comment: I would say you should put `:normal yygccpi` in the last column instead of just `yygccpi` to have it type it exactly as in normal mode.. I can't remember the exact reason we use `:normal` instead, but `:normal` is exactly as typing it key by key in `---[NORMAL]---` mode. Normally you'd use `:normal!` (plus asterisk) to ignore mappings, but I'm pretty sure gcc is a mapping so thats not what you want in this case :) read also `:help :normal`

Comment: Or just use `nmap`, no need to `:normal`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change you mapping to `nmap` instead of `nnoremap`.

`nnoremap` uses "default" mappings on the right mapped side (it doesn't allow nested mappings, like `gcc`).

Thus

```
nmap yc yygccpi
```