# How to map a keybind to an already existing keybind provided by plugin

Tags: key-bindings

```
-- commenting single line
keymap("n", "<C-/>", "gcc", opts)
```

This is the line in my lua config for keybinds.
I am using this plugin for commenting keybinds:

```
use({
            "numToStr/Comment.nvim",                                -- keybinds for commenting
            config = function()
                require("Comment").setup()
            end
        })
```

This plugin maps `gcc` ie. pressing g and then c and then c key combination to allow commenting and uncommenting. I wanna remap this to `<C-/>` so what changes do I make in my keybinds config lua?

To summarize:
My plugin maps `gcc` to allow me to comment and uncomment and I wanna map `<C-/>` key combination to `gcc` so that it does the same job.

Comment: Normally to map to an already existing mapping, you would use the "recursive" variant (like `:nmap \ gcc` or something). Sometimes it's easier to map to the underlying implementation, especially when `<Plug>` mappings are used.

Comment: However, it's a little unclear to me what exactly you are asking. Can you please [edit] to clarify what is mapped by the plugin and what you desire?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I have made some changes to try and explain my problem better, lemme know if you need any more clarifications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/22589/18609

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22590/42821), try `nmap` instead of `noremap`.

If you're using `vim.keymap.set()`, remap option (inverse of noremap) is set to false by default. You can set it to true as follows:

`vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-/>", "gcc", { remap = true })`

See `:help vim.keymap.set()` for more.

Alternatively you can check `:map gcc` to see what it is bound to and use that for binding it your desired keys.